# NMake Pattern Rules

Tags: c++, compilation, makefile, nmake

Hi I decided to try and learn how to build programs via the command line and makefiles instead of relying on Visual Studio to do it for me. After familiarizing myself with the process of compiling into .obj files and linking, I moved onto NMake. I've written a basic makefile to try and compile source files located in multiple folders into .obj files, link each folder of .obj files into .lib files and then link the .lib files into a .exe file.

```
CC=cl /c /EHsc /Fo
LIB=lib /OUT:
LINKER=link /OUT:
EXEC_NAME=Test.exe
DEL=del
MAKE=nmake
OUT=.\out

all: $(OUT)\*.lib
    $(LINKER)$(EXEC_NAME) *.lib

clean:
    $(DEL) $(OUT)

rebuild:
    $(MAKE) clean
    $(MAKE) all

$(OUT)%.lib: $(OUT)\%\*.obj
    $(LIB)%.lib $(OUT)%\*.obj

%(OUT)\%\:
    $(CC)$(OUT)\%\ .\%\*.cpp
```

When I try to run it with `nmake all` it tells me: `NMAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make '.\out\*.lib'`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

This question was understandably ignored for a year-and-a-half but has lately attracted 4 upvotes.

No question is actually stated but the implied question is: *Why can't `nmake` follow the %-pattern rules in my makefile?*

The answer to that is MS `nmake` does not support %-pattern rules at all. [The documentation of MS `nmake`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd9y37ha.aspx) and of its [inference rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hxwz9ch.aspx) is easily found.

[GNU `make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) and some other make tools support [%-pattern rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html). The makefile here would also fail in GNU `make` due to obvious blunders.

Comment: Actually GNU make [also knows of the older form without `%`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Suffix-Rules.html), calling them old-fashioned suffix rules.

Comment: The question should be "is there any `nmake.exe` alternative which supports pattern-rules", possible answer: the "[jom.exe](https://github.com/top-master/make-jom/releases)" is an open-source alternative, and they may accept such Pull-request.